# How to change all of the columns in a table to NULL if they are empty

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm importing a lot of data from an excel file using the SSIS package. Thus, Excel contains some empty columns. I'd like to make it Null.

I'm now updating a blank column to NULL using the query below.

```
UPDATE TT 
SET DEATHDATE = NULL
FROM TEMP_TABLE TT 
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(DEATHDATE)) = ''

UPDATE TT 
SET CURRENTDATE= NULL
FROM TEMP_TABLE TT 
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(CURRENTDATE)) = ''

UPDATE TT 
SET City = NULL
FROM TEMP_TABLE TT 
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(City )) = ''
```

OR

```
UPDATE TT 
SET BIRTHDATE = NULL
FROM TEMP_TABLE TT 
WHERE DATALENGTH(BIRTHDATE) = 0
```

This update statement will update to **NULL** if the specified column records are **EMPTY**.

But I don't like doing this. I want to change all of the records in the table. If there are **EMPTY** records in that table, I want to change them to **NULL**.

Is that even possible? Thank you in advance

Comment: You have to specify each column you want to update. And I'd probably do a separate UPDATE for each column.

Comment: Why are these apparent dates even strings?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I'm using the SSIS package to import data from an excel file. so i import the date types as NVARCHAR

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all these into a single update, using a `CASE` to decide whether to overwrite the value or not.

```sql
UPDATE TT 
SET DEATHDATE   = CASE WHEN TRIM(DEATHDATE)   = '' THEN NULL ELSE DEATHDATE END,
    CURRENTDATE = CASE WHEN TRIM(CURRENTDATE) = '' THEN NULL ELSE CURRENTDATE END,
    BIRTHDATE   = CASE WHEN TRIM(BIRTHDATE)   = '' THEN NULL ELSE BIRTHDATE END
FROM TEMP_TABLE TT 
WHERE TRIM(DEATHDATE) = ''
  OR  TRIM(CURRENTDATE) = ''
  OR  TRIM(BIRTHDATE) = '';
```

You calso shorten the expressions to `CASE WHEN TRIM(DEATHDATE) <> '' THEN DEATHDATE END` etc, but I think the above is clearer.

Quite why you are storing dates in a text column is a different question. All I can say is: don't.

Comment: I'm using the SSIS package to import data from an excel file. If I select the dates data type, certain records won't insert properly.

Comment: I suggest you fix the data *before* you import it

Comment: I tried, but I couldn't find a way to fix the data before importing it.